# Flex: disable hand cursor when mouse is over toggle button bar

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How can I disable the use of hand cursor when over a toggle button bar? I've tried with
 `useHandCursor = false` but it had no effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting `buttonMode = false` as well. I don't know if that is even set to true (should be) on that component, but it is worth a shot. It does cause the hand cursor to show up when true.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a little of your code? Because i seem, according to the examples on this [page](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/22/creating-a-vertical-togglebuttonbar-in-flex/), it is not necessary to set useHandCursor property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this：

useHandCursor = false;
buttonMode = false;